# Crear rangos de diferente longitud en R usando for y while loops

Tags: r, bucle-for, while

quiero hacer un loop en R que como resultado guarde un rango cuyo tamaño minimo sea 1000 e incremente su tamaño 10 puntos cada vez que la condicion no se cumple.
Les mando el script que tengo pero no estoy teniendo el resultado que quiero.

```
set.seed(123)

newbins = seq(0,5000,1000)
binLength = 1000
stepSize = 10
blocks=NULL
end = 0


for (b in newbins[1:length(newbins)-1]){
  tempBP = 0
  tempBP_new = 0
  start = end +1
  end = binLength
  while (sum(tempBP_new-tempBP) < 0.40){
    tempBP_new = tempBP
    tempBP_new = runif(1)*0.5
    binLength = binLength + stepSize
    blocks = rbind(blocks,c(start, end))
  }
}
blocks
```

El output del script es:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1 1000
 [2,]    1 1000
 [3,]    1 1000
 [4,]    1 1000
 [5,] 1001 1040
 [6,] 1041 1050
 [7,] 1041 1050
 [8,] 1041 1050
 [9,] 1051 1080
[10,] 1051 1080
[11,] 1051 1080
[12,] 1081 1110
[13,] 1081 1110
[14,] 1081 1110
[15,] 1081 1110
[16,] 1081 1110
```

Pero yo quiero algo como por ejemplo

```
   1 1000
1001 2040
2041 3050
3050 5000
```

O sea cada rango debe ser de al menos 1000 y el loop tiene que terminar cuando se llega al 5000. Tampoco entiendo por qué tengo el mismo resultado varias veces en el loop.
Tienen algunas ideas?? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

A la primera pregunta pregunta de por que tienes el valor varias veces es por que la variable start y end solo cambian cuando se cumple la función que esta dentro de while por lo que mientras no se cumpla va seguir dando el mismo resultado, esto sucede porque dentro del while asignas

> binLength = binLength + stepSize

cuando si quisieras que cambiara tendrías que asignarlo a

> end = binLength + stepSize

De igual manera te aconsejo que no utilices "end" y "start" ya que ya son funciones predefinidas en la libraria stat  y creo que pudiera generar algún problema,

Otro punto importante es que dentro del for tienes un menos 1 por

> for (b in newbins[1:length(newbins)-1])

Por lo que el loop solo llegaría a 4000 mil,

Realice algunas modificaciones en el código cambiando la palabra end por final y la palabra start por inicio ,

```
   set.seed(123)

   newbins = seq(0,5000,1000)
   binLength = 1000
   stepSize = 10
   blocks=NULL
   final= 0


   for (b in newbins[2:length(newbins)]){
       tempBP = 0
       tempBP_new = 0
       inicio = final +1
       final = b
       binLength=b
       print(final)
    #Para quitar la necesidad de tener el menos 1 al inicio puse una condición que el valor de b tiene que ser menor a 5000
    while (sum(tempBP_new-tempBP) < 0.40 | b < 5000){
    tempBP_new = tempBP
    tempBP_new = runif(1)*0.5
    binLength= binLength + stepSize
    #Se igual la variable final para a binLength para que el valor de blocks cambie
    final=binLength

    blocks = rbind(blocks,c(inicio, final))
 }
}
blocks

      [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1 1010
  [2,]    1 1020
  [3,]    1 1030
  [4,]    1 1040
  [5,] 1041 2010
  [6,] 2011 3010
  [7,] 2011 3020
  [8,] 2011 3030
  [9,] 3031 4010
  [10,] 3031 4020
  [11,] 3031 4030
```

Los cambios que realice los marco en los comentarios dentro del código, espero haber entendido bien lo que se necesitaba y que el código te funcione